# Find integers $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $x^2 + i\,y^2 = 9+ 4i$.

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, gaussian-integers

I want to know if the Gaussian prime $\mathfrak{p} = 9 + 4i$ is the sum of <del>two squares</del> [square] $+$ $i \,\times $ [square] in the ring of [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.  So I can write down an equation:

\begin{eqnarray*} x^2 + i\, y^2 &=& \mathfrak{p} \\ 
(a+bi)^2 +  i\,(c+di)^2 &=& 9 + 4i\end{eqnarray*}

These can reduce to a pair of equations over $\mathbb{Z}$ which could also be solved:

\begin{eqnarray*} (a^2 - b^2) + 2cd &=& 9 \\ 
2ab + (c^2 - d^2) &=& 4\end{eqnarray*}

Now we have $2$ equations and $4$ unknowns, so ostensibly we have $4 - 2 = 2$ degrees of freedom.  I am looking for at least one solution, or to show there are finitely many.

Comment: Did you meant $x^2+y^2=9+4i$ instead?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $x^2+y^2$ was the old question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568780/find-integers-x-y-in-mathbbzi-such-that-x2-y2-8-5i).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Note that the OP wrote “$9+4i$ is the sum of two squares”. What that means is that $9+4i$ can be written as $x^2+y^2$, not that it can be written as $x^2+iy^2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That's what I say. Just look at the old question.

Comment: The equation here is $x^2 + {\color{#8F7E3F}{i}} y^2 = 9 + 4i$ as I have written.

Comment: @cactus314 And you also wrote “sum of two squares”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solutions are the real special cases $x=\pm 3,\,y=\pm 2$.

To prove only finitely many solutions exist note $|x|^4+|y|^4=97$, writing $97$ as the sum of two squares. This gives $a^2+b^2=|x|^2,\,c^2+d^2=|y|^2$ only finitely many possible values, each of which only has finitely many solutions in $a,\,b,\,c,\,d$.

Answer (score 0):

Just try $x=3+0i$ and $y=2+0i$.

Comment: is that all of them?

Comment: No, but there is finite number solutions $z$ with $|z|=|9+4i|$.